# Distributed Jmeter max number of servers

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter, load-testing, distributed-testing

I use distributed jmeter for load tests in Kubernetes. To maximize the number of concurrent threads I use several Jmeter server instances.

My test plan has 2000 users, so I have 10000 concurrent users with 5 Jmeter servers. Each user send 1 request per second to Kafka. This runs without any problems.

But if I increase the number of server instances up to 10, Jmeter gets a lot of errors when sending requests and is not able to send the required rate of requests per second.

Is there a way to use more than 5 server instances in Jmeter (my cluster has 24vCPUs and 192gb ram)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretical maximum value of slaves is very high, you can have as many as [2 147 483 647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647) slaves which is a little bit more than 5.

So my expectation is that the problem is somewhere else, i.e. there is a [maximum number of connections per IP](http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html) defined or the broker is running out of resources

We cannot give meaningful advices unless we have more details, in the meantime you can check:

- [jmeter.log files](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for master and slaves
- [response data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)
- kafka logs
- resource consumption on kafka broker(s) side, it can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)